# Determine if a mesh is visible on the viewport according to current camera

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I have been developing an app with `three.js` but I have encountered this problem and I cannot seem to find any solution to it.
I want to determine which meshes are visible right now according to where the camera is currently aiming, so i can refresh my objects (data is coming from a service) or not depending on if they are being shown on the viewport.

I'm using `THREE.js` in CANVAS mode (I have found a solution using WebGL that says if objects are rendered or not, but i need CANVAS for this project).

I have been trying to find if `three.js` sets somehow a property to indicate whether the object is visible or not (currently on the screen, not on the entire 3D world), but I can't find it. Meshes have a visible: property but it's always on true even if the camera is not aiming to that object.

Comment: research frustrum culling

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the code you're after:

```
var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
var cameraViewProjectionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

// every time the camera or objects change position (or every frame)

camera.updateMatrixWorld(); // make sure the camera matrix is updated
camera.matrixWorldInverse.getInverse( camera.matrixWorld );
cameraViewProjectionMatrix.multiplyMatrices( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse );
frustum.setFromMatrix( cameraViewProjectionMatrix );

// frustum is now ready to check all the objects you need

console.log( frustum.intersectsObject( object ) );
```

Comment: im trying the code but im getting "undefined method" with cameraViewProjectionMatrix.multiplyMatrices, do you know why? was your intent to use .multiply(a, b) ? thanks.

Comment: Oh nonono, my bad. Using old version of three.js (rev 54). I'll update.

Comment: Will this work with a specific triangle/face? How could it be referenced?

Comment: Works great for me thanks! Now how can I move an object from any vector outside the frustum to the opposite side of the frustum (goal: respawn the object there after it moves out of view). Question created here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826091/trying-to-respawn-an-object-frustum-intersectsobject-not-working-in-while-loop

Comment: I'm getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined" when using this? Has this been outdated or something (r71)?

Comment: I was having a strange problem detecting fake intersections (with elements that in fact are not visible in the viewport) and applying this function to check it worked perfectly. Thanks!