# Threejs - Detect canvas limits in the camera world

Tags: three.js

Is there a way to determine the max / min values for height and width in the threejs coordinate system?

I'm (kinda) aware of the [Frustum / Projection matrix thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624021/determine-if-a-mesh-is-visible-on-the-viewport-according-to-current-camera), but I can't quite see the whole picture, I'd be glad if someone could illuminate me on this, with some practical example, since I'm pretty new to all this and I'm struggling a little to get my head around it.

The first think that came to my head to solve this problem was to create a mesh and use it as a dummy to detect the boundaries of the canvas, but I was wondering if it would be a more convenient way to achieve this.

Just FYI I need this for a script that should draw a 2d grid of lines, with a fixed camera.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350875/three-js-width-of-view/13351534#13351534

Comment: It sounds like you are drawing in 2D? Maybe you should be using an OrthographicCamera.

Comment: yeah ur guess is right. I'm in the 2d realm. for the moment I figured that out by using the @WestLangley link, but thanks for the heads up, I'll check it out asap.